# How to get start and end date from quarters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails 5 app.
I need to be able to get the dates that is from a current quarter. With that I mean the user will provide me with a selected quarter (1 to 4) and I will convert that number to a start and end date for that selected quarter. How can I do that?

**This is how I tried it but it is good?**

```
def quarter_date(quarter, year)
    if quarter == 1
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-01-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-03-#{year}"))
    elsif quarter == 2
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-04-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-06-#{year}"))
    elsif quarter == 3
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-07-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-09-#{year}"))
    elsif quarter == 4
      where(date_at: Time.parse("01-10-#{year}")..Time.parse("01-12-#{year}"))
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Updated it now with my attempt.

Comment: Even though my solution might have worked for you, you should wait for some time before accepting it as an answer. The reason for this is that someone might have a better/another way of doing it, but people seem to skip adding answers to questions with accepted answers. Waiting can get you more options on how to solve your problem. Upvote is okay. Upvote represents that solution works for you. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
require 'date'

today = Date.today
 => #<Date: 2018-07-02 ((2458302j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

year = today.year
 => 2018

input = 3

start_date = Date.new(2018, input * 3 - 2, 1)
 => #<Date: 2018-07-01 ((2458301j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

end_date = Date.new(2018, input * 3 + 1, 1) - 1
 => #<Date: 2018-09-30 ((2458392j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

It returns the start and end dates for the given quarter of current year.

**Update**

Updated with method from your attempt:

```
def quarter_date_range(quarter, year)
  start_date = Time.parse("#{year}-#{quarter * 3 - 2}-1")
  end_date = (start_date + 2.months).end_of_month
  where(date_at: start_date..end_date)
end
```